# How to draw images fast in OGLES2.0 with android?

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es-2.0

I have a little bit knowledge of android and `OGLES2.0` but when i am drawing a picture it takes approximately 0.4ms. So I can draw only 40 pictures in 16ms in order to get 60fps for my game.
Here is my `GLRenderer` code:
The important parts are the Render-method and the Sprite Class.

```
 public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {
    // Our matrices
    private final float[]   mtrxProjection          = new float[16];
    private final float[]   mtrxView                = new float[16];
    private final float[]   mtrxProjectionAndView   = new float[16];

    // Geometric variables
    public static int[]     vertices;
    public static short[]   indices;
    public static int[]     uvs;
    public IntBuffer        vertexBuffer;
    public ShortBuffer      drawListBuffer;
    public IntBuffer        uvBuffer;
    public List<Sprite>     sprites;
    public int[]            texturenames;
    public MainActivity     mainActivity;
    // Our screenresolution
    float                   mScreenWidth            = 1280;
    float                   mScreenHeight           = 720;
    float                   ssu                     = 1.0f;
    float                   ssx                     = 1.0f;
    float                   ssy                     = 1.0f;
    float                   swp                     = 1280.0f;
    float                   shp                     = 720.0f;
    Update                  update;
    Images                  images;

    // Misc
    Context                 mContext;
    long                    mLastTime;
    int                     mProgram;

    public GLRenderer (MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mContext = mainActivity;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        this.mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 100;
        this.sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    }

    public void onPause () {
        /* Do stuff to pause the renderer */
    }

    public void onResume () {
        /* Do stuff to resume the renderer */
        this.mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame (GL10 unused) {

        // Get the current time
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // We should make sure we are valid and sane
        if (this.mLastTime > now) return;

        // Get the amount of time the last frame took.
        long elapsed = now - this.mLastTime;
        System.out.println(elapsed);
        // clear Screen and Depth Buffer, we have set the clear color as black.
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Drawing all static things like the background
        drawStatics();

        for (Opponent opponent: this.update.opponents) {
            int position = this.sprites.indexOf(opponent.getSprite());

            // Rotate the sprite
            this.sprites.get(position).rotate((float) Math.toRadians(opponent.getAngle()));

            // Create the image information
            SetupImage(opponent.getPicture(), 0);

            // Update our example
            UpdateSprite(position);

            // Render our example
            Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);
        }

        for (Tower tower: this.update.towers) {
            long a = System.nanoTime();
            int position = this.sprites.indexOf(tower.getSprite());

            // Rotate the sprite
            this.sprites.get(position).rotate((float) Math.toRadians(tower.getAngle()));

            // Create the image information
            SetupImage(tower.getPicture(), 0);

            // Update our example
            UpdateSprite(position);

            // Render our example
            Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);
            System.out.println("time: " + (System.nanoTime() - a));
        }

        for (Bullet bullet: this.update.bullets) {
            int position = this.sprites.indexOf(bullet.getSprite());

            // Rotate the sprite
            this.sprites.get(position).rotate((float) Math.toRadians(bullet.getAngle()));

            // Create the image information
            SetupImage(bullet.getPicture(), 0);

            // Update our example
            UpdateSprite(position);

            // Render our example
            Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);
        }

        for (SuperExplosion explosion: this.update.explosions) {
            int position = this.sprites.indexOf(explosion.getSprite());

            // Rotate the sprite
            // sprites.get(position).rotate((float)Math.toRadians(explosion.getAngle()));

            // Create the image information
            SetupImage(explosion.getPicture(), 0);

            // Update our example
            UpdateSprite(position);

            // Render our example
            Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);
        }

        drawStatics2();

        // Save the current time to see how long it took :).
        this.mLastTime = now;
        //      System.out.println("höhe "+mScreenHeight+"        breite "+ mScreenWidth);

    }

    private void drawStatics () {
        // Ground
        // Update our example
        long h = System.nanoTime();
        UpdateSprite(0);
        //      for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        //          System.out.println("vertices [" + i + "]: " + vertices[i]);
        //      }
        // Render our example
        Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 1);
        System.out.println("time: " + (System.nanoTime() - h));
        // Bar
        // Update our example
        UpdateSprite(1);

        // Render our example
        Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 2);

        if (!this.update.upgrade) {
            if (this.update.normalSpeed) {
                // Update our example
                UpdateSprite(2);

                // Render our example
                Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 3);
            } else {
                // Update our example
                UpdateSprite(3);

                // Render our example
                Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 4);
            }
            if (!this.update.start) {
                // Update our example
                UpdateSprite(4);

                // Render our example
                Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 5);
            }
        }

        // UpgradeBar
        if (this.update.upgrade) {
            // Update our example
            UpdateSprite(6);

            // Render our example
            Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 7);
        }
        h = System.nanoTime();
        // Bunny1
        // Update our example
        UpdateSprite(7);

        // Render our example
        Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 8);
        System.out.println("time bunny1 " + (System.nanoTime() - h));
        // CarrotTower
        // Update our example
        UpdateSprite(8);

        // Render our example
        Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 9);

        // MineThrower
        // Update our example
        UpdateSprite(9);

        // Render our example
        Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 10);

        // BunnyKing
        // Update our example
        UpdateSprite(10);

        // Render our example
        Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 11);

    }

    private void drawStatics2 () {
        // Life
        // Update our example
        UpdateSprite(5);

        // Render our example
        Render(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 6);
    }

    private void Render (float[] m, int index) {

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "vPosition");

        // Enable generic vertex attribute array
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_INT, false, 0, this.vertexBuffer);

        // Get handle to texture coordinates location
        int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "a_texCoord");

        // Enable generic vertex attribute array
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

        // Prepare the texturecoordinates
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_INT, false, 0, this.uvBuffer);

        // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "uMVPMatrix");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, m, 0);

        // Get handle to textures locations
        int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "s_texture");

        // Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture.
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mSamplerLoc, index);

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.texturenames[index]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, this.drawListBuffer);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged (GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

        // We need to know the current width and height.
        this.mScreenWidth = width;
        this.mScreenHeight = height;

        // Redo the Viewport, making it fullscreen.
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, (int) this.mScreenWidth, (int) this.mScreenHeight);

        // Clear our matrices
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            this.mtrxProjection[i] = 0.0f;
            this.mtrxView[i] = 0.0f;
            this.mtrxProjectionAndView[i] = 0.0f;
        }

        // Setup our screen width and height for normal sprite translation.
        Matrix.orthoM(this.mtrxProjection, 0, 0f, this.mScreenWidth, 0.0f, this.mScreenHeight, 0, 50);

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(this.mtrxView, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(this.mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, this.mtrxProjection, 0, this.mtrxView, 0);

        // Setup our scaling system
        SetupScaling();

        // Create the GroundSprite
        SetupTriangle(this.images.ground_1.getWidth(), this.images.ground_1.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.bar1.getWidth(), this.images.bar1.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.speed1.getWidth(), this.images.speed1.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.speed2.getWidth(), this.images.speed2.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.start.getWidth(), this.images.start.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.life.getWidth(), this.images.life.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.upgradeBar.getWidth(), this.images.upgradeBar.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.bunny1.getWidth(), this.images.bunny1.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.carrotTower.getWidth(), this.images.carrotTower.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.mineThrower.getWidth(), this.images.mineThrower.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        SetupTriangle(this.images.bunnyKing1.getWidth(), this.images.bunnyKing1.getHeight(), 0, 0);

        this.sprites.get(0).translate(this.ssx * this.images.ground_1.getWidth() / 2, this.ssy * this.images.ground_1.getHeight() / 2);
        this.sprites.get(1).translate(this.ssx * (this.images.bar1.getWidth() / 2) + this.ssx * 1084.0f, this.ssy * this.images.bar1.getHeight() / 2.0f);

        this.sprites.get(2).translate(this.ssx * this.images.speed1.getWidth() / 2 + this.ssx * 20, this.mScreenHeight - (this.ssy * this.images.speed1.getHeight() / 2) - this.ssy * 5);
        this.sprites.get(3).translate(this.ssx * this.images.speed2.getWidth() / 2 + this.ssx * 20, this.mScreenHeight - (this.ssy * this.images.speed2.getHeight() / 2) - this.ssy * 5);
        this.sprites.get(4).translate(this.ssx * this.images.start.getWidth() / 2 + this.ssx * 120, this.mScreenHeight - (this.ssy * this.images.start.getHeight() / 2) - this.ssy * 5);
        this.sprites.get(5).translate(this.ssx * this.images.life.getWidth() / 2 + this.ssx * 5, this.ssy * this.images.life.getHeight() / 2 + this.ssy * (20));
        this.sprites.get(6).translate(this.ssx * this.images.upgradeBar.getWidth() / 2, this.ssy * this.images.upgradeBar.getHeight() / 2);

        this.sprites.get(7).translate(this.ssx * (this.images.bunny1.getWidth()) + this.ssx * (1280 - 143 - (this.images.bunny1.getWidth() / 2)), this.mScreenHeight - (this.ssy * this.images.bunny1.getHeight() / 2) - (this.ssy * (235 + (this.images.bunny1.getHeight() / 2))));
        this.sprites.get(8).translate(this.ssx * (this.images.carrotTower.getWidth()) + this.ssx * (1280 - 53 - (this.images.carrotTower.getWidth() / 2)), this.mScreenHeight - (this.ssy * this.images.carrotTower.getHeight() / 2) - (this.ssy * (235 + (this.images.carrotTower.getHeight() / 2))));
        this.sprites.get(9).translate(this.ssx * (this.images.mineThrower.getWidth()) + this.ssx * (1280 - 143 - (this.images.mineThrower.getWidth() / 2)), this.mScreenHeight - (this.ssy * this.images.mineThrower.getHeight() / 2) - (this.ssy * (325 + (this.images.mineThrower.getHeight() / 2))));
        this.sprites.get(10).translate(this.ssx * (this.images.bunnyKing1.getWidth()) + this.ssx * (1280 - 53 - (this.images.bunnyKing1.getWidth() / 2)), this.mScreenHeight - (this.ssy * this.images.bunnyKing1.getHeight() / 2) - (this.ssy * (325 + (this.images.bunnyKing1.getHeight() / 2))));

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated (GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Setup our scaling system
        SetupScaling();

        // Set the clear color to black
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);

        // Blending
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

        // How should opengl blend it
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        // Create the shaders, solid color
        int vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_SolidColor);
        int fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_SolidColor);

        riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor = GLES20.glCreateProgram(); // create empty
                                                                    // OpenGL ES
                                                                    // Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, vertexShader); // add
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // vertex
                                                                            // shader
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, fragmentShader); // add
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // fragment
                                                                                // shader
                                                                                // to
                                                                                // program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor); // creates OpenGL ES
                                                            // program
                                                            // executables

        // Create the shaders, images
        vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_Image);
        fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_Image);

        riGraphicTools.sp_Image = GLES20.glCreateProgram(); // create empty
                                                            // OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, vertexShader); // add the
                                                                        // vertex
                                                                        // shader
                                                                        // to
                                                                        // program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, fragmentShader); // add
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // fragment
                                                                        // shader
                                                                        // to
                                                                        // program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image); // creates OpenGL ES
                                                        // program executables

        // Set our shader programm
        GLES20.glUseProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);

        // Creating a Images Object
        this.images = new Images(this.mainActivity.getResources());

        // Loading the Bitmaps
        this.images.load();

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(this.update = new Update(this.mainActivity, this, this.images), 16);

        // Generate Textures, if more needed, alter these numbers.
        this.texturenames = new int[24];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(24, this.texturenames, 0);
        SetupImageStatics();
    }

    private void SetupImageStatics () {

        SetupImage(this.images.ground_1, 1);
        SetupImage(this.images.bar1, 2);
        SetupImage(this.images.speed1, 3);
        SetupImage(this.images.speed2, 4);
        SetupImage(this.images.start, 5);
        SetupImage(this.images.life, 6);
        SetupImage(this.images.upgradeBar, 7);
        SetupImage(this.images.bunny1, 8);
        SetupImage(this.images.carrotTower, 9);
        SetupImage(this.images.mineThrower, 10);
        SetupImage(this.images.bunnyKing1, 11);
    }

    public void SetupScaling () {
        // The screen resolutions
        this.swp = (this.mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
        this.shp = (this.mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);

        // Orientation is assumed portrait
        this.ssx = this.swp / 1280.0f;
        this.ssy = this.shp / 720.0f;

        // Get our uniform scaler
        if (this.ssx > this.ssy) this.ssu = this.ssy;
        else this.ssu = this.ssx;
    }

    public void processTouchEvent (MotionEvent me) {
        switch (me.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                this.update.x = (int) me.getX();
                this.update.y = (int) me.getY();
                this.update.getItemOrUpgrade(this.update.x, this.update.y);
                this.update.fastForward(this.update.x, this.update.y);
                this.update.start(this.update.x, this.update.y);
                this.update.nextUpgrade(this.update.x, this.update.y);

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (this.update.tower != 0) {
                    this.update.x = (int) me.getX();
                    this.update.y = (int) me.getY();

                    this.update.pathPlace(this.update.x, this.update.y);
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                this.update.x = (int) me.getX();
                this.update.y = (int) me.getY();

                this.update.placeOrReleaseItem = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateSprite (int location) {
        // Get new transformed vertices
        vertices = this.sprites.get(location).getTransformedVertices();

        // The vertex buffer.
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        this.vertexBuffer = bb.asIntBuffer();
        this.vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        this.vertexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void SetupImage (Bitmap bmp, int index) {
        // Create our UV coordinates.
        uvs = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 };

        // The texture buffer
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uvs.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        this.uvBuffer = bb.asIntBuffer();
        this.uvBuffer.put(uvs);
        this.uvBuffer.position(0);

        // // Retrieve our image from resources.
        // int id =
        // mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/ic_launcher", null,
        // mContext.getPackageName());
        //
        // // Temporary create a bitmap
        // Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
        // id);

        // Bind texture to texturename
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + index);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.texturenames[index]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

        // // We are done using the bitmap so we should recycle it.
        // bmp.recycle();

    }

    public void SetupTriangle (float width, float height, float x, float y) {
        // Get information of sprite.
        this.sprites.add(new Sprite(width, height, x, y));
        vertices = this.sprites.get(this.sprites.size() - 1).getTransformedVertices();

        // The order of vertexrendering for a quad
        indices = new short[] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

        // The vertex buffer.
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        this.vertexBuffer = bb.asIntBuffer();
        this.vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        this.vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        this.drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        this.drawListBuffer.put(indices);
        this.drawListBuffer.position(0);
    }

    class Sprite {
        float   angle;
        float   scale;
        RectF   base;
        Point   translation;

        public Sprite (float width, float height, float x, float y) {
            // Initialise our intital size around the 0,0 point
            this.base = new RectF(-(width / 2f) * GLRenderer.this.ssu, (height / 2f) * GLRenderer.this.ssu, (width / 2f) * GLRenderer.this.ssu, -(height / 2f) * GLRenderer.this.ssu);

            // Initial translation
            this.translation = new Point(Math.round(x * GLRenderer.this.ssu), Math.round(y * GLRenderer.this.ssu));

            // We start with our inital size
            this.scale = 1f;

            // We start in our inital angle
            this.angle = 0.0f;
        }

        public void translate (float deltax, float deltay) {
            // Update our location.
            this.translation.x += Math.round(deltax);
            this.translation.y += Math.round(deltay);
        }

        public void scale (float deltas) {
            this.scale += deltas;
        }

        public void rotate (float deltaa) {
            this.angle += deltaa;
        }

        public int[] getTransformedVertices () {
            // Start with scaling
            int x1 = Math.round(this.base.left * this.scale);
            int x2 = Math.round(this.base.right * this.scale);
            int y1 = Math.round(this.base.bottom * this.scale);
            int y2 = Math.round(this.base.top * this.scale);

            // We now detach from our Rect because when rotating,
            // we need the seperate points, so we do so in opengl order
            Point one = new Point(x1, y2);
            Point two = new Point(x1, y1);
            Point three = new Point(x2, y1);
            Point four = new Point(x2, y2);

            // We create the sin and cos function once,
            // so we do not have calculate them each time.
            float s = (float) Math.sin(this.angle);
            float c = (float) Math.cos(this.angle);

            // Then we rotate each point
            one.x = Math.round(x1 * c - y2 * s);
            one.y = Math.round(x1 * s + y2 * c);
            two.x = Math.round(x1 * c - y1 * s);
            two.y = Math.round(x1 * s + y1 * c);
            three.x = Math.round(x2 * c - y1 * s);
            three.y = Math.round(x2 * s + y1 * c);
            four.x = Math.round(x2 * c - y2 * s);
            four.y = Math.round(x2 * s + y2 * c);

            // Finally we translate the sprite to its correct position.
            one.x += this.translation.x;
            one.y += this.translation.y;
            two.x += this.translation.x;
            two.y += this.translation.y;
            three.x += this.translation.x;
            three.y += this.translation.y;
            four.x += this.translation.x;
            four.y += this.translation.y;

            // We now return our float array of vertices.
            return new int[] { Math.round(one.x), Math.round(one.y), 0, Math.round(two.x), Math.round(two.y), 0, Math.round(three.x), Math.round(three.y), 0, Math.round(four.x), Math.round(four.y), 0, };
        }
    }

    public class Update extends TimerTask {
        Bitmap                  ball;
        int                     x, y;

        int                     mapStage            = StaticVariables.getMap();
        int                     towerCost           = 200;
        boolean                 start               = false;
        int                     x2                  = 0;
        int                     y2                  = 0;
        public int              points              = 50000;
        public boolean          stageClear          = false;
        boolean                 everythingSpawned   = false;
        public int              life                = 200;
        private int             space               = 40;
        public boolean          stageLose           = false;
        public boolean          upgrade             = false;
        List<Opponent>          opponents           = new ArrayList<Opponent>();
        List<Tower>             towers              = new ArrayList<Tower>();
        List<Bullet>            bullets             = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
        List<SuperExplosion>    explosions          = new ArrayList<SuperExplosion>();
        List<Path>              paths               = new ArrayList<Path>();
        List<int[]>             stages              = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        private List<Integer>   minesPassive        = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        private List<Integer>   removeBulletsIndex  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer>           removeMinesPassive  = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        public int              time                = 16;
        public int              speed               = 1;
        public int              stageLevel          = 1;
        public boolean          placePossible       = true;
        private int             timeTimes           = 0;
        private int             bubble              = 0;
        public boolean          wait                = false;
        public int              mapLength;

        boolean                 change              = false, change1 = false, change2 = false, change3 = false;
        double                  maxX, maxY, minX, minY, abstandX2, abstandX, abstandY2, abstandY, shortestSpacing, shortest, angleMaxX, angleMaxY, angleMinX, angleMinY, angleAbstandX, angleAbstandY;
        int                     shortestIndex, index, spawnCounter = 0;
        private MediaPlayer     bubblePopSound;
        private int             tower               = 0;
        int                     nextImage           = 0;
        private boolean         normalSpeed         = true;
        float                   invisability        = 1;
        private int             upgradeBarDiff      = 0;
        private boolean         hideUpgradeBar      = false;
        public int              iceBallRotation;
        private int             explosionTime;
        private List<MinePlace> minesPlaced         = new ArrayList<MinePlace>();
        private int             gameLocation        = 0;
        Localizer               localizer;
        int                     testCounter;
        boolean                 load                = true;
        private boolean         placeOrReleaseItem  = false;
        double                  viewWidth, viewHeight;
        MergeSort               mergeSort           = new MergeSort();
        GLRenderer              glRenderer2;

        public List<Integer> getMinesPassive () {
            return this.minesPassive;
        }

        public void setMinesPassive (int index2, int minesPassive) {
            this.minesPassive.set(index2, minesPassive);
        }

        public void addMinesPassive (int minesPassive) {
            this.minesPassive.add(minesPassive);
        }

    public void addMinesPassive (int i, Integer minesPassive) {
        this.minesPassive.add(i, minesPassive);

    }   
   }
```

I hope you know a method to improve the drawing speed.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to say how to increase performance in your case. Too much noise in code from my perspective. But generally speaking there are some basic tips on how to increase performance during rendering:
 - avoid unnecessary OpenGl state machine changes 
 - avoid unnecessary OpenGl state querying (e.g. GLES20.glGetAttribLocation()) 
 - avoid memory allocations during rendering
 - use simplest shaders possible
 - use texture atlases to avoid necessary texture binds 
 - use VBOs whenever possible

For more information on subject try to read https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Performance. Or see this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLVbLVtjDDw.

You may also consider using libGDX http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ it will handle drawing sprites efficient way for you.